# Setting JFrame icon through NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, embedded-resource

I'm trying to set an Icon for a `JFrame` through NetBeans. In the `Design` tab of the frame, i'm selecting the `IconImage` from it's properties menu and it tells me to write a custom code inside `Form.setIconImage( );` the parenthesis. I've tried writing two lines inside the parenthesis:

1. `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Game.class.getResource("/images/snake.png"))`
2. `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/snake.png"))`

`images` is a package inside the source package. Everytime i try to run the code, it throws me an error `Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1`

But this only happens when I try to set an image icon. Otherwise, the code executes perfectly. I can't seem to find the solution. If anyone could suggest me to do to anything other than this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the icon is even *included in the Jar* created by the IDE? AFAIR only images within the `resources` directory are included.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Unfortunately, the jar file which the IDE has created is neither running on the terminal nor can i extract it's content. Also, the name of my project is ```SnakeLadders``` but the jar file name is ```SnakeLadders-1.0-SNAPSHOT```. Is there any way i can set the image externally. Without putting it in my resources.

Comment: *"the jar file which the IDE has created is neither running on the terminal nor can i extract it's content"* 1) The SDK has a 'jar tool' that can list the content of a Jar. OTOH (on Windows) I'd just (copy &) rename the archive to a .zip and open it using the OS. 2) One of the ways to debug a Jar is to run it from the command line in order to see any error output. This requires that the stack traces are not caught & ignored, but it sounds as though this code is outputting them as it should.